# euler project sum-of-primes, and Stream.view

Tags: scala

Looking at the Project Euler solutions at http://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/, I got a bit confounded by how a view comes in to play in the solution for "Problem 10
Calculate the sum of all the primes below two million."

The proposed solution is:

```
lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: ps.map(i => Stream.from(i + 1).find(
    j => ps.takeWhile(k => k * k <= j).forall(j % _ > 0)).get)
val r = ps.view.takeWhile(_ < 2000000).foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
```

...which results in `142913828922`

I noticed you get a different result, `1179908154`, if you leave out the view:

```
val r = ps.takeWhile(_ < 2000000).foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
```

Can someone explain to me why these are different?

Comment: I guess it's a bug ... seems Stream is a "high maintenance date".

Comment: What scala version? I'm getting 142913828922 in 2.8.0 and 2.8.1 with both view and non view version...

Comment: $ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.8.1.final -- Copyright 2002-2010, LAMP/EPFL
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode)

Comment: Oh look, with a fresh repl, I get the same result both ways. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: ps.map(i => Stream.from(i + 1).find(
     |     j => ps.takeWhile(k => k * k <= j).forall(j % _ > 0)).get)
ps: Stream[Int] = <lazy>

scala> val r = ps.view.takeWhile(_ < 2000000).foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
r: Long = 142913828922

scala> val r = ps.takeWhile(_ < 2000000).foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
r: Long = 142913828922
```

Comment: Thanks ... in my comment above I indicated this went away with a fresh repl, so evidently this was a repl or scala bug that's difficult to reproduce.