# Scala Stream[Int]#foldLeft and Stream[Int]#sum give different results

Tags: scala

This question relates to [euler project sum-of-primes, and Stream.view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137063/euler-project-sum-of-primes-and-stream-view), but there is a bit of a twist. I want to calculate the sum of all the primes below two million. I create a generator of prime numbers defined as:

```
lazy val primes: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(i =>
  primes.takeWhile(j => j * j <= i).forall(i % _ > 0))
```

I wrote two tests, one using Stream[Int]#foldLeft and one using Stream[Int]#sum:

```
 @Test
 def testEuler010a {
   primes.view.takeWhile(_ < 2000000).foldLeft(0L)(_ + _) mustEqual 142913828922L
 }

 @Test
 def testEuler010b {
   primes.view.takeWhile(_ < 2000000).sum mustEqual 142913828922L
 }
```

`testEuler010a` gives me the right answer while `testEuler010b` does not with an answer of `1179908154`.  I would expect that `Stream[Int]#foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)` would be identical to `Stream[Int].sum`, but it is not. Even if I materialize the Stream with a `toList()`, I get he same discrepancy. Is it an incorrect assumption that those methods should give the same result?

I'm using Scala 2.9.1.final.

Comment: My usage of `view` isn't necessary. Performance is not improved in this case nor do I get a different result.

Comment: Note that `142913828922L % (Int.MaxValue.toLong + 1)` is equal to the value that the `sum` version gives.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to be overflow. These give the same results for me:

```
(primes map (_.longValue) takeWhile (_ < 2000000)).sum
(primes map (_.longValue) takeWhile (_ < 2000000)).foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
```

I suppose the difference between `sum` and `foldLeft` is that the result type of `sum` is the same as the type of the elements being summed over (as required by the [Numeric trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html)), but `foldLeft` can have a different result type, which you achieve by writing `0L`.